# Wicket 6.x https with other host

Tags: wicket, wicket-6

I have a webpage with a area where users can login. This area

> www.host.com/mypage/myarea

should be under https.

The problem is that my https is running on a another host:

> www.something-foo.host.com/mypage/myarea

. (loadbalancer stuff...??? I dont know why)

My try is to annotate the Pages with @RequireHttps, an than rewrite the urls of the Pages.

But how and where? Has someone please an example?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Well if you really want to this with Wicket your best option would be to write an implementation of `IRequestMapperDelegate` and set them during the `onInit()` process of your WicketApplication.

To give you an idea how to do this I've written an example of raping the HttpsMapper of Wicket:

```
    setRootRequestMapper(new HttpsMapper(getRootRequestMapper(), new HttpsConfig(8080, 8443)) {
        private final static String SUBDOMAIN = "www.something-foo.";

        @Override
        protected Scheme getSchemeOf(Request request) {
            HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) ((WebRequest) request).getContainerRequest();
            // well that's basically cheating and not so nice... but we're not allowed to overwrite mapRequest()
            // but that means that every request that doesn't start with the subdomain will be treated as HTTP aka
            // insecure.
            if (req.getServerName().startsWith(SUBDOMAIN) == false) {
                return Scheme.HTTP;
            }

            return super.getSchemeOf(request);
        }

        @Override
        protected String createRedirectUrl(IRequestHandler handler, Request request, Scheme scheme) {
            // stolen from super implementation
            HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) ((WebRequest) request).getContainerRequest();
            String url = scheme.urlName() + "://";
            // except the part where we insert the subdomain
            url += SUBDOMAIN;
            url += req.getServerName();
            if (!scheme.usesStandardPort(getConfig())) {
                url += ":" + scheme.getPort(getConfig());
            }
            url += req.getRequestURI();
            if (req.getQueryString() != null) {
                url += "?" + req.getQueryString();
            }
            return url;

        }
    });
```

Depending on your question I can't really determine if this is a good solution ... it really depends on how many frameworks are working on top of Wicket. Since you didn't mention anything else I'm assuming none.